# Precedence/co-existence of SPF and DKIM

Tags: email, spf, dkim

Is co-existence of SPF and DKIM specified somewhere (assuming the absence of DMARC)?

I want to put only my own IPs in the SPF and let 3rd parties send mail on behalf of my domain using DKIM.

What happens to e-mail that has a valid DKIM signature but fails SPF check (SPF FAIL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on how any given recipient has configured their mail server.  Mine would refuse it outright because of the SPF failure, assuming you have `-all` at the end of your record (as you most certainly should).  Someone else's mail server might do something completely different.

SPF and DKIM are two completely separate systems; you cannot make up for a failure in one by an accomodation in the other.

Comment: +1 My servers are the same way. A "fail" in either gets your message put in the Junk folder or bounced.

Answer (score 0):

You can control what will happen in this case with a email standard called [DMARC](http://dmarc.org/).

It gives you the option to specify whether you require both or either of the checks to fail, before the message is marked as spam. Of course this have to be supported by the receiving mail server, but almost all of the major services and most of the MTA software supports it so it's safe bet.

Comment: You cannot control other servers. I would say with DMARC "you can advise what should happen..." -- It is entirely up to the receiver whether they use DMARC at all (and read your advise) and whether they follow it.

Comment: I've explained this in my comment - it's up to the receiving mail server, and the major providers are supporting and even encouraging it. What is more of a server check both of the options, he will most probably have DMARC enabled.